# Java Azure Function With EventGrid Trigger Timing Out

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, appinsights

I am trying to write an Azure Function that would be triggered by EventGrid. I have been following the official documentation and stood up required resources. EventGrid topic, Function App, AppInsight etc. I wrote an basic function that just logs the message that it has been invoked. When I sent the message to topic, I can see the matrices of topic and subscription but all of them indicate that all messages were failed. App insight logs says the app is invoked but I don't see the messages in log analytics's `trace` table. I added custom logger but still same result. Not only the logs are not present in log analytics the app insight logs says function is timing out, considering there is no business logic in the function why is it running for that long.

My intention of this function was to learn function app, but now I am lost in trying to find the issue. I am trying to understand

1. Why all invocations failed(snapshot below).

[image]

2. Why it is timing out when there is no business logic.

I would really appreciate some inputs here on what I am missing or doing wrong. Some helpful snapshots are below.

**Before adding loggers class looks like this**
[image]

**After adding loggers class looks like this**
[image]

**Logger configuration**
[image]

**Message I am sending to topic**

```
    [{
  "id": "123",
  "eventType": "Type",
  "subject": "Subject",
  "eventTime": "2023-01-10T21:03:07+00:00",
  "data": {
    "SourceBlobUrl": "Source",
    "DestinationBlobUrl": "Destination"
  },
  "dataVersion": "1.0",
  "metadataVersion": "1",
  "topic": "/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/topic"
}]
```

**host.json**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  },
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Error",
      "Function.BlobCopy": "Warning",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "enableLiveMetrics": true,
      "enableDependencyTracking": true,
      "enablePerformanceCountersCollection": true,
      "httpAutoCollectionOptions": {
        "enableHttpTriggerExtendedInfoCollection": true,
        "enableW3CDistributedTracing": true,
        "enableResponseHeaderInjection": true
      }
    }
  },
  "healthMonitor": {
    "enabled": true,
    "healthCheckInterval": "00:00:30",
    "healthCheckWindow": "00:02:00",
    "healthCheckThreshold": 6,
    "counterThreshold": 0.80
  }
}
```

**Exception Stack**

```
[
    {
        "severityLevel": "Error",
        "outerId": "0",
        "message": "Timeout value of 00:10:00 was exceeded by function: Functions.BlobCopy",
        "type": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException",
        "id": "1793742",
        "parsedStack": [
            {
                "assembly": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.36.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35",
                "method": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryHandleTimeoutAsync>d__35.MoveNext",
                "level": 0,
                "line": 663,
                "fileName": "C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"
            },
            {
                "assembly": "System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
                "method": "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw",
                "level": 1,
                "line": 0
            },
            {
                "assembly": "System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
                "method": "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess",
                "level": 2,
                "line": 0
            },
            {
                "assembly": "System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
                "method": "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification",
                "level": 3,
                "line": 0
            },
            {
                "assembly": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.36.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35",
                "method": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<InvokeWithTimeoutAsync>d__33.MoveNext",
                "level": 4,
                "line": 571,
                "fileName": "C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"
            },
            {
                "assembly": "System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
                "method": "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw",
                "level": 5,
                "line": 0
            },
            {
                "assembly": "System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
                "method": "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess",
                "level": 6,
                "line": 0
            },
            {
                "assembly": "System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
                "method": "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification",
                "level": 7,
                "line": 0
            },
            {
                "assembly": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.36.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35",
                "method": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__32.MoveNext",
                "level": 8,
                "line": 527,
                "fileName": "C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"
            },
            {
                "assembly": "System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
                "method": "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw",
                "level": 9,
                "line": 0
            },
            {
                "assembly": "System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
                "method": "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess",
                "level": 10,
                "line": 0
            },
            {
                "assembly": "System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
                "method": "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification",
                "level": 11,
                "line": 0
            },
            {
                "assembly": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.36.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35",
                "method": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__26.MoveNext",
                "level": 12,
                "line": 306,
                "fileName": "C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"
            },
            {
                "assembly": "System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
                "method": "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw",
                "level": 13,
                "line": 0
            },
            {
                "assembly": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.36.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35",
                "method": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__26.MoveNext",
                "level": 14,
                "line": 352,
                "fileName": "C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"
            },
            {
                "assembly": "System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
                "method": "System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw",
                "level": 15,
                "line": 0
            },
            {
                "assembly": "System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
                "method": "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess",
                "level": 16,
                "line": 0
            },
            {
                "assembly": "System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e",
                "method": "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification",
                "level": 17,
                "line": 0
            },
            {
                "assembly": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.36.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35",
                "method": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext",
                "level": 18,
                "line": 108,
                "fileName": "C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionExecutor.cs"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```